# Find duplicates in a multidimensional array and echo out them

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, array-unique

I want to find duplicates in a multidimensional array and then echo out which one who has duplicates and which not. I've tried this code.

```
    $teams = array
  (
  "grupp_A" => array('Arsenal','Arsenal','Barcelona'),
  "grupp_B" => array('Milan','Man United','Barcelona'),
  "grupp_C" => array('Juventus','Barcelona','Barcelona'),
  "grupp_D" => array('Arsenal','Man United','Barcelona')
  );



foreach ( $teams as $key => $val ) {

  foreach($val as $k => $v) {

    if(count(array_unique($k))<count($k))
{
    echo "Array: $v has duplicates<br>";
}
else
{

    echo "Array: $v does not have duplicates<br>";
    }
    }
    }
```

Then I get the result

```
Array: Arsenal has duplicates
Array: Arsenal has duplicates
Array: Barcelona has duplicates
Array: Milan has duplicates
Array: Man United has duplicates
Array: Barcelona has duplicates
Array: Juventus has duplicates
Array: Barcelona has duplicates
Array: Barcelona has duplicates
Array: Arsenal has duplicates
Array: Man United has duplicates
Array: Barcelona has duplicates
```

But the result should look like this.

```
Array: grupp_A has duplicates
Array: grupp_C has duplicates
Array: grupp_B does not have duplicates
Array: grupp_D does not have duplicates
```

I'm stuck and don't know what I do wrong and need some help here.

I tried this code with in_array as suggested.

```
foreach ( $teams as $key => $val ) {

    if (in_array($key, $val)) {

    echo "Array: $key has duplicates<br>";
}
else
{

    echo "Array: $key does not have duplicates<br>";
    }
    }
```

Which gave the output

```
Array: grupp_A does not have duplicates
Array: grupp_B does not have duplicates
Array: grupp_C does not have duplicates
Array: grupp_D does not have duplicates
```

A bit closer but not there yet.

Comment: what about using `in_array`?

Comment: I've edited my post. Came a bit closer but not there yet. Any suggestions what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one loop is enough, as you aggregate the clubs :

```
foreach($teams as $group => $clubs)
{
    if( count(array_unique($clubs)) < count($clubs) )
        echo "Group $group has duplicates" . PHP_EOL ;
    else
        echo "Group $group has no duplicates" . PHP_EOL ;
}
```

Output :

> Group grupp_A has duplicates
>
> Group grupp_B has no duplicates
>
> Group grupp_C has duplicates
>
> Group grupp_D has no duplicates

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had to do two loops beacause it was a multidimensional array. What is the PHP_EOL doing? Haven't seen that before.

Comment: It is the "end of line" constant, platform independent. It will be converted to '\r\n' on Windows, '\n' on Unix, ...

Answer (score 0):

I liked your `array_unique` approach, so sorry about throwing you off with my comment about `in_array`.

```
foreach ($teams as $key => $val) {
    if (count(array_unique($val)) == count($val)) {
        echo $key . " has no duplicates" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $key . " has duplicates" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, problem. Always good to fiddle around and learn more things. As I asked Joffrey, what is the PHP_EOL thing? Never seen that before?

Comment: it's the php version of <br>